# Why is ClassLoader an abstract class?

Tags: java, classloader, abstract-class

`ClassLoader` is an abstract class, even though it doesn't have any abstract methods. Why is that so? Are there any other abstract classes without abstract methods?

Answer (score 5):

A class with abstract methods has to be abstract. However, an abstract class doesn't have to have abstract methods.

Generally, **a class should be abstract whenever it doesn't make sense conceptually for instances of that class to exist**. Having incomplete implementation is one example of this (and it happens to be enforced by the compiler), but it's not the only example.